# How to add Datetime picker to product attribute in admin?

Tags: magento2

I have added product attribute as follows

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                    'product_activation',
                    [
                        'type' => 'datetime',
                        'backend' => '',
                        'frontend' => '',
                        'label' => 'Product Activation Timestamp',
                        'input' => 'date',
                        'class' => '',
                        'source' => '',
                        'time'      =>    true,
                        'date_format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
                        'time_format' => 'hh:mm:ss',
                        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                        'visible' => true,
                        'required' => false,
                        'user_defined' => false,
                        'default' => '',
                        'searchable' => false,
                        'filterable' => false,
                        'comparable' => false,
                        'visible_on_front' => false,
                        'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                        'unique' => false,
                        'apply_to' => ''
                    ]
                );
```

Still unable to get the datetime picker in my admin product form.

Please help me to solve this

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code :

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * Install attributes
 */
class InstallData implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory
     */
    protected $categorySetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
    }
     public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $setup->startSetup();

        $categorySetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'product_activation',
            [
                'type' => 'datetime',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Frontend\Datetime',
                'label' => 'Product Activation Timestamp',
                'input' => 'date',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => true,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '',
                'sort_order' => 9,
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => ''
            ]
        ); 

         $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding `'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\Datetime',` would make it validate and format the date according to the Magento standards